# APK fails to be installed on any device

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm new in the Xamarin Development world so I installed Visual Studio 2017 with all the needed cross compiler features.
After downloading and updating the SDKs for Android API 23, 24, 25 and 26 and some corresponding emulator images I got the emulators starting up.
I created a base Xamarin Android App within VS, compiled and deployed it to the simulator.

By deploying/installing the generated APK to the simulator I get the following error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/BlankAndroid.BlankAndroid-1: Package /data/app/BlankAndroid.BlankAndroid-1/base.apk code is missing]
```

It doesn't matter which SDK I choose as “Target Framework” or which Simulator I choose (Android 6, Android 7 or 7.1). The result is the same: The apk is not installed, but the “Mono Shared Runtime” are present and will be updated.

I figured out that the created apk file does not contain a file “classes.dex” or any oder dex files just some ressources. A file “classes.zip” in the directory “obj\Debug\android\bin\classes” with the generated java classes out of my C# is present. These files should be compiled with the DEX-Compiler to the classes.dex file, when I understood correctly.

Even other sample projects from the Internet have exactly the same result.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: [Take a look this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/77142/help-with-new-deployment-issue-for-my-forms-app-install-failed-dexopt-from-xamarin-studio/p2).

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved by fresh installing the Android SDK and all related components. It seemed to have a SDK missmatch between an old Google Android SDK and the new installed Xamarin Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and tried many solutions from the search in web but this one to an extent solved that deploy failure issue.

1. In the emulator, open settings -> Apps -> Uninstall your app if it is listed
2. Deploy the app from visual studio again.

This solved the problem that said base.apk is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your project back to the current recommended defaults. Remove all of the following properties from the .csproj file:

- AndroidEnableMultiDex
- AndroidDexGenerator
- AndroidLinkTool
- AndroidDexTool

This will let Xamarin.Android pick the current latest default values, this apply for Visual Studio for Mac and VS 2017-2019